# Problems with dask after updating Anaconda in Windows

Tags: python, anaconda, dask

I was correctly working with Dask.distributed using Delayed and Futures in Windows but I am running into problems after updating my anaconda environment today using the following commands:

```
conda update conda
conda update anaconda
conda update spyder
```

What was working previously is not working now. Even the following simple code is not working:

```
from dask.distributed import Client

client = Client(n_workers=4)

from time import sleep

def inc(x):
    sleep(1)
    return x + 1

def add(x, y):
    sleep(1)
    return x + y

from dask import delayed
x = delayed(inc)(1)
y = delayed(inc)(2)
z = delayed(add)(x, y)
z.compute()
```

It gets stuck and does not provide a solution. I tried also to see the execution flow by printing something in the beginning of inc and add functions, but the system is not printing anything. I attach a figure of dask dashboard in case it helps [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7XoK.png). I also attach the result of a client.get_versions. Do you know whether there is any incompatibility of dask with any new versions of related packages? Any clue about what could be happening?

```
client.get_versions(check=True)
    {'scheduler': {'host': (('python', '3.7.3.final.0'),
   ('python-bits', 64),
   ('OS', 'Windows'),
   ('OS-release', '10'),
   ('machine', 'AMD64'),
   ('processor', 'Intel64 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 13, GenuineIntel'),
   ('byteorder', 'little'),
   ('LC_ALL', 'None'),
   ('LANG', 'None'),
   ('LOCALE', 'None.None')),
  'packages': {'required': (('dask', '2.1.0'),
    ('distributed', '2.1.0'),
    ('msgpack', '1.0.0'),
    ('cloudpickle', '1.3.0'),
    ('tornado', '6.0.4'),
    ('toolz', '0.10.0')),
   'optional': (('numpy', '1.18.1'),
    ('pandas', '1.0.3'),
    ('bokeh', '2.0.0'),
    ('lz4', None),
    ('dask_ml', None),
    ('blosc', None))}},
 'workers': {'tcp://192.168.0.13:56997': {'host': (('python', '3.7.3.final.0'),
    ('python-bits', 64),
    ('OS', 'Windows'),
    ('OS-release', '10'),
    ('machine', 'AMD64'),
    ('processor', 'Intel64 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 13, GenuineIntel'),
    ('byteorder', 'little'),
    ('LC_ALL', 'None'),
    ('LANG', 'None'),
    ('LOCALE', 'None.None')),
   'packages': {'required': (('dask', '2.1.0'),
     ('distributed', '2.1.0'),
     ('msgpack', '1.0.0'),
     ('cloudpickle', '1.3.0'),
     ('tornado', '6.0.4'),
     ('toolz', '0.10.0')),
    'optional': (('numpy', '1.18.1'),
     ('pandas', '1.0.3'),
     ('bokeh', '2.0.0'),
     ('lz4', None),
     ('dask_ml', None),
     ('blosc', None))}},
  'tcp://192.168.0.13:56998': {'host': (('python', '3.7.3.final.0'),
    ('python-bits', 64),
    ('OS', 'Windows'),
    ('OS-release', '10'),
    ('machine', 'AMD64'),
    ('processor', 'Intel64 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 13, GenuineIntel'),
    ('byteorder', 'little'),
    ('LC_ALL', 'None'),
    ('LANG', 'None'),
    ('LOCALE', 'None.None')),
   'packages': {'required': (('dask', '2.1.0'),
     ('distributed', '2.1.0'),
     ('msgpack', '1.0.0'),
     ('cloudpickle', '1.3.0'),
     ('tornado', '6.0.4'),
     ('toolz', '0.10.0')),
    'optional': (('numpy', '1.18.1'),
     ('pandas', '1.0.3'),
     ('bokeh', '2.0.0'),
     ('lz4', None),
     ('dask_ml', None),
     ('blosc', None))}},
  'tcp://192.168.0.13:57001': {'host': (('python', '3.7.3.final.0'),
    ('python-bits', 64),
    ('OS', 'Windows'),
    ('OS-release', '10'),
    ('machine', 'AMD64'),
    ('processor', 'Intel64 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 13, GenuineIntel'),
    ('byteorder', 'little'),
    ('LC_ALL', 'None'),
    ('LANG', 'None'),
    ('LOCALE', 'None.None')),
   'packages': {'required': (('dask', '2.1.0'),
     ('distributed', '2.1.0'),
     ('msgpack', '1.0.0'),
     ('cloudpickle', '1.3.0'),
     ('tornado', '6.0.4'),
     ('toolz', '0.10.0')),
    'optional': (('numpy', '1.18.1'),
     ('pandas', '1.0.3'),
     ('bokeh', '2.0.0'),
     ('lz4', None),
     ('dask_ml', None),
     ('blosc', None))}},
  'tcp://192.168.0.13:57003': {'host': (('python', '3.7.3.final.0'),
    ('python-bits', 64),
    ('OS', 'Windows'),
    ('OS-release', '10'),
    ('machine', 'AMD64'),
    ('processor', 'Intel64 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 13, GenuineIntel'),
    ('byteorder', 'little'),
    ('LC_ALL', 'None'),
    ('LANG', 'None'),
    ('LOCALE', 'None.None')),
   'packages': {'required': (('dask', '2.1.0'),
     ('distributed', '2.1.0'),
     ('msgpack', '1.0.0'),
     ('cloudpickle', '1.3.0'),
     ('tornado', '6.0.4'),
     ('toolz', '0.10.0')),
    'optional': (('numpy', '1.18.1'),
     ('pandas', '1.0.3'),
     ('bokeh', '2.0.0'),
     ('lz4', None),
     ('dask_ml', None),
     ('blosc', None))}}},
 'client': {'host': [('python', '3.7.3.final.0'),
   ('python-bits', 64),
   ('OS', 'Windows'),
   ('OS-release', '10'),
   ('machine', 'AMD64'),
   ('processor', 'Intel64 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 13, GenuineIntel'),
   ('byteorder', 'little'),
   ('LC_ALL', 'None'),
   ('LANG', 'None'),
   ('LOCALE', 'None.None')],
  'packages': {'required': [('dask', '2.1.0'),
    ('distributed', '2.1.0'),
    ('msgpack', '1.0.0'),
    ('cloudpickle', '1.3.0'),
    ('tornado', '6.0.4'),
    ('toolz', '0.10.0')],
   'optional': [('numpy', '1.18.1'),
    ('pandas', '1.0.3'),
    ('bokeh', '2.0.0'),
    ('lz4', None),
    ('dask_ml', None),
    ('blosc', None)]}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it. For some reason Anaconda is not installing the last version of dask library. So just updating the dask package to the last version solved the problem.

Comment: To help others, you may want to be more specific with what "updating anaconda" meant in the original question. Do you mean to say that the latest version of the anaconda installer ("anaconda individual edition") does not install the latest dask? Then specify exactly how you updated it.